# php's date_create_from_format() returns false during validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, datetime

I have a simple html form, one of the fields is for `datetime-local`.

```
<div>
   <label for="published_at">Publish date:</label>
   <input type="datetime-local" name="published_at" id="published_at" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($published_at); ?>">
</div>
```

Nothing too fancy, but while validating the form input, I keep getting an error and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
if ($published_at != '') {
     echo $published_at; // prints - 2020-08-25T17:56 
     // exit;

     $date_time = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y H:i', $published_at);

     if ($date_time === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid date and time'; // it ends up here, so date_create_from_format() returns false for whatever reason. This is what i cant figure out
     }
     else {

        $date_errors = date_get_last_errors();
        echo $date_errors;
        exit;

        if ($date_errors['warning_count'] > 0) {
           $errors[] = 'Invalid date / time';
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You're missing the `\T` in your format, because your time string has a T in it

Comment: How am I supposed to write the forma then? I tried `'d-m-Y\T H:i'` but it's not that

Comment: Because you're adding a space to it. The format needs to match exactly what is being passed in.

Comment: Yes, `'Y-m-d\TH:i'` this did the trick